# Track link clicks for URL posted on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, url-routing

I am currently using a php function to track links click count . My link is something like

**http://www.itswittyviralfeed.com/feedseven/677b1ee6f3a9a8724860bb22fc63d813**

when user hits the link it goes through the function and route to org link stored in db against id "**677b1ee6f3a9a8724860bb22fc63d813**".

I restricted the function to save only clicks those are from Facebook by check "**HTTP_REFERER**". Function is working fine it is saving data in database.

But the count of clicks is far more then the clicks showing on Facebook insight (people reached) and google analytics.  Don't know why. Is there any other solution to track links and get data to be stored in db ? or anything that can help in this situation.

Comment: Is the link redirected to another page?, Perhaps the clicked location is directing the address of direct link background.

Comment: @DenizAktürk yes it is redirecting to another website/page. but sory but i didn't get what you mean by directing direct link background . can you please explain

Comment: Links clicked through facebook or google may be redirecting themselves to the source connection by keeping the forwarded addresses in memory.

Comment: That is, the page you count clicks on may not be visited for this reason.

Comment: so how can i count exact clicks ?

Comment: Source addresses belong to your site?

Comment: @DenizAktürk I have 4,5 domains like "**http://www.itswittyviralfeed.com/**" which are pointing to the same website where the above given url is generated. The end url where user goes at end is not on my site say it is "www.google.com"

Comment: What you use as a forwarding status? like 301, 302?

Comment: no.. i have a rewrite rule in htaccess that point all the urls which have "**feeseeven**" with thm to a specific function which check the id as mentioned above get the org link and after saving route to org link .